# Mysql FK referenced column not show results

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have problem with creating FK. Am checking and checking and i cant see what is wrong.
I have **product**, **sites** and **product_site_ref** tables.
When i try to add FK to table product_site_ref i cant choose referenced column. Check screenshot.[image]

**Relation table**

```
CREATE TABLE `product_site_ref` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `site_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_index` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Product table**

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(125) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(225) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Site table**

```
CREATE TABLE `site` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(245) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Note: table proizvod on screenshot is product. I just translate for your goys to better understand. All is the some

Comment: You may refer to the column only when this column is indexed.

Comment: i have created index